# Settings that integrate gives also distributions as solutions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, distributions

How can I tell Mathematica that I also want distributions as solutions for Integrate?
Example:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}kx}\mathrm{d}x=2\pi\delta(x)$$

Comment: It sounds like what you want here is `FourierTransform`, which does produce distributions: `FourierTransform[1, x, k, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]`.

Comment: This improper integral diverges. The Fourier transform of $1$ is not defined through it.

Comment: @user64494 yes but I was hoping that there exists something like „PrincipalValue -> True“ for distributions.

Comment: No, it is not true. E.g. see English Wiki/Fourier transform/Tempered distributions for info.